# How to run this PHP code?

Tags: php, forms, api, post

I am trying to run this php file thru XAMPP apache server. But it sends me an error:
[image]

May be I need to create some HTML form to Initialize fields and include some libraries to work with PHP code?

```
<?php           
$username = {testName};
$password = {1234567};
$secret = {yoursecret};
$token = $username.'--'.md5($password).'--'.md5($username.$password.$secret).'/';
$string = "CreateNewLead";
$post = array();
$post['first_name'] = "First";
$post['last_name'] = "Last";
$post['email'] = "email@";blabla.com$post['lead_status'] = "Hot";
$post['lead_source'] = "Direct Mail";
$post['lead_supplier'] = "Supplier1";
$post['city'] = "London";
$post['zip_code'] = "111111";
$post['country'] = "United Kingdom";
$post['address'] = "Street 100";
$post['phone'] = "123456789";
$post['prefix'] = "234";
www.testingurl.com$post['ip'] = "111.222.111.222";
$post['state'] = "State";
$post['language'] = "en";
$post['secondary_email'] = "bla.bla@";
bla.com$post['affiliate_id'] = "12441232";
$post['referrer_id'] = "TST123";
$post['registration_country'] = "United Kingdom";
$post['other_phone'] = "234567890";
$url = 'http://blabla123.somedesign.net/api/v1/';
$ch = curl_init($url.$token.$string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$get = json_decode($data);
var_dump($get);
?>
```

Comment: `$username = {testName};` is not valid PHP

Comment: `$username = {testName};` try to use `$username = 'testName';` did you have a tutorial that explain the code above?

Comment: I have no idea what that code block is for but hashing passwords with MD5 is not the way to go. For user passwords you should use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: This code is for CRM inetgration thru API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$username = 'testName';
$password = '1234567';
$secret = 'yoursecret';
```

use a pair of single quote.

Comment: nah, its different `www.testingurl.com`, `bla.com`, lots syntax error there